# Why RMap interface not have a removeAll method? and what's the most convenient way to do batch delete?

Tags: java, redis, redisson

I see RMap (https://static.javadoc.io/org.redisson/redisson/3.5.6/org/redisson/api/RMap.html) has putAll, getAll methods, why not have a removeAll methods?

And what's the most convenient way to batch delete data from a RMap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RMap.fastRemove` method, it accepts multiple keys as parameter